# PageView navigation Buttons need to be tapped 2 times to actually work (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a List of BoardingPage widgets that I build a pageview with. I have some navigation buttons on the bottom of the Pageview that the user can use to go to the next or previous page.
However, these buttons need to be tapped twice in order to do something and I don't know how to fix this behaviour.

Codesnippet:
https://pastebin.com/kuZ8Hhvf

```
class _BoardingState extends State<Boarding> {
  int currentPage = 0;
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MyLocalization localization = MyLocalization.of(context);
    String title = "notitle";
 
    Widget circleBar(bool isActive) {
      return AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 150),
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
        height: isActive ? 12 : 8,
        width: isActive ? 12 : 8,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: isActive ? myDarkGreen : myDefaultBackgroundColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
        ),
      );
    }
 
    void setPage(int pageID) {
      setState(() {
        currentPage = pageID;
      });
    }
 
    return Consumer<Settings>(builder: (context, settings, _) {
      PageController pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
 
      if (settings.isFirstStartDone()) {
        return widget.child;
      }
 
      return Stack(
        children: [
          PageView.builder(
              controller: pageController,
              physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              onPageChanged: (page) {
                setState(() {
                  currentPage = page;
                });
              },
              itemCount: boardingList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                BoardingPage boardingSite = boardingList[index];
                //widget.title = boardingSite.title;
                return boardingSite.body;
              }),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  for (int i = 0; i < boardingList.length; i++)
                    if (i == currentPage) ...[circleBar(true)] else ...[circleBar(false)],
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //Boarding finished Button
          Visibility(
              visible: currentPage == boardingList.length - 1,
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20, right: 30),
                child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    child: FloatingActionButton(
                        backgroundColor: myDarkGreen,
                        onPressed: () {
                          //Saving Town
                          settings.setProfilesetting(0, 0, "townname", boardingTownName);
                          settings.setProfilesetting(0, 0, "dreamaddress", boardingDreamAddress);
                          settings.setSouthernRegion(0, boardingTownRegion == "south");
                          settings.setProfilesetting(0, 0, "townfruit", boardingTownFruit);
                          settings.setTownExisting(0, true);
                          settings.setActiveTownID(0);
 
                          //Saving Character
                          settings.setProfilesetting(0, 0, "charactername", boardingCharacterName);
                          settings.setProfilesetting(0, 0, "friendcode", boardingCharacterFriendcode);
                          settings.setProfilesetting(0, 0, "gender", boardingCharacterGender);
                          settings.setProfilesetting(0, 0, "creatorid", boardingCharacterCreatorID);
                          settings.setProfilesetting(0, 0, "joindate", boardingCharacterJoinDate);
                          settings.setProfilesetting(0, 0, "birthday", boardingCharacterBirthday);
                          settings.setProfilesetting(0, 0, "townleader", true.toString());
                          settings.setCharacterExisting(0, 0, true);
 
                          //Saving Characterlook
                          settings.setCharacterRenderValues(0, 0, boardingActiveItems);
 
                          settings.setActiveCharacterID(0);
                          settings.setFirstStartDone(true);
                          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                            return widget.child;
                          }));
                        },
                        child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                        ))),
              )),
          //Page forward Button
          Visibility(
              visible: currentPage != boardingList.length - 1 && currentPage != 0,
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  child: FlatButton(
                      color: myDarkGreen,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                      child: currentPage != 4
                          ? Icon(
                              Icons.arrow_forward,
                              color: myWhite,
                            )
                          : Text(localization.no, style: TextStyle(color: myWhite)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (currentPage == 4) {
                              settings.setSpoilerfilter(false);
                              settings.setSpoilerFilterSeen(true);
                            }
                        pageController.animateToPage(currentPage++, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250), curve: Curves.bounceInOut);
                      }),
                ),
              )),
          //Page back Button
          Visibility(
              visible: currentPage != boardingList.length - 1 && currentPage != 0,
              child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                  child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: FlatButton(
                          color: myDarkGreen,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                          child: currentPage != 4
                              ? Icon(
                                  Icons.arrow_back,
                                  color: myWhite,
                                )
                              : Text(localization.yes, style: TextStyle(color: myWhite)),
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (currentPage == 4) {
                              settings.setSpoilerfilter(true);
                              settings.setSpoilerFilterSeen(true);
                            }
 
                            pageController.animateToPage(currentPage--, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250), curve: Curves.bounceInOut);
                          })))),
          //First screen create button
          Visibility(
            visible: currentPage == 0,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100.0),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: FlatButton(
                              color: myDarkGreen,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                              child: Text(
                                "Create",
                                style: TextStyle(color: myWhite),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () => pageController.animateToPage(currentPage++, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250), curve: Curves.bounceInOut))),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //first screen skip button
          Visibility(
            visible: currentPage == 0,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40.0),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: FlatButton(
                              color: myDarkGreen,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                              child: Text(
                                "Skip",
                                style: TextStyle(color: myWhite),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                pageController.animateToPage(4, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250), curve: Curves.bounceInOut);
                                currentPage = 5;
                              })),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      );
    });
  }
 
  Future<void> _migrateSettings() async {
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by replacing currentPage++ with ++currentPage (currentPage-- as well) so the page will get counted up before the navigation will be executed